# Do animals drown in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The title is self explanatory.  I have a means of gathering animals without wheat via water as the flow is controlled by a push of a button (the beginnings of an auto harvester).  I have a glass ceiling only 1 block high (per schema of my place). So once the water fills the room, it will push the animals to one side(no space between the top of the water and the ceiling).  This then sparked the question, **will they drown before getting to the desired location by flow of the water?**

**Can they drown at all?**

I have seen this post  [on how to round up animals](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19546/any-way-to-round-up-animals-in-minecraft) but it didn't answer my original question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Animals can drown.

They follow the same rules as everything else (except for slimes and endermen) and float in water. If you have an air block above the level of the water then they should be able to breathe just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Mobs do different things in water:

- Most mobs will drown if their head is underwater, exactly like the player. Slimes will drown.
- Squid will not drown (!) but will suffocate when *not* in water.
- Endermen will immediately teleport if exposed to water, so cannot drown.
- Blazes are damanged by *all* contact with water, so I'm not sure if they can drown because they'll die from water exposure first anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes animals can drown but I don't think its possible for them to drown unless they stay in 2 block deep water for a period of time, But I think it would be safer for you to put your animal in 1 block deep water unless its a cow or mob to be on the safer side but I'm pretty sure that the only other real way they can drown Is if they have a block off some sort on top of them